# Don't try this at home

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

To make this recipe, you'll need a really good kitchen
Our neighbors, for example, couldn't even use it to make a chicken
Above all, your temperature setting has to be good
Otherwise it won't work, and you won't get any food
When you've set up the ingredients, add water and wait
It may take a while, don't be alarmed if it gets late
When it's done it'll be worth it, I promise you that
You'll have so much to eat, I'm sure you'll get fat

The one time we tried it, it was quite a success
Though I dare say it made a bit of a mess
Now tell me, my friends: what came out - can you guess?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Life

To make this recipe, you'll need a really good kitchen

> Earth is a unique planet with the conditions "just right" for life

Our neighbors, for example, couldn't even use it to make a chicken

> Any other planet in our solar system failed to create complex life forms

Above all, your temperature setting has to be good

> Earth is fairly mild relative to all the other planets out there

Otherwise it won't work, and you won't get any food

> No complex life forms found on other planets (yet)

When you've set up the ingredients, add water and wait

> Earth had the right chemistry, conditions and water (possibly from comets) to produce simple life

It may take a while, don't be alarmed if it gets late

> It took millions of years for life to rise on earth, even with proper conditions

When it's done it'll be worth it, I promise you that

> The fact that so many species exist on this planet is a beautiful thing

You'll have so much to eat, I'm sure you'll get fat

> Lots of living things to eat

The one time we tried it, it was quite a success

> So far we know abiogenesis has only happened on our planet. As a result of that, millions of species (and counting) exist today: quite successful given that there were possibly very few to begin with.

Though I dare say it made a bit of a mess

> The interactions between living organisms are messy. The mess could also refer to our actions - polluting the planet.

Comment: Correct - good job! You were two minutes late compared to @kamenf's answer, but I'm selecting this as the accepted answer because: 1. This answer is slightly better written; 2. You are new on this site and I feel like you would better benefit from the encouragement of an accepted answer; 3. I have a feeling that both your and kamenf's answers were inspired by a comment posted by ruakh a few minutes before your answers were posted, so really ruakh should get a lot of the credit anyway.

Comment: I don't feel the second-to-last point fits. @BigBlackBox is that part correct?

Comment: @cst1992 Yes, everything is essentially correct. The last few lines could be a bit better explained perhaps (see kamenf's answer).

Comment: @Big Black Box Oh wow thanks, I don't think I deserved it! I will edit the answer to be more fitting

Comment: @Symmetry thanks, very nice solution indeed and your explanations are now spot on.

Answer (score 12):

It could be

> Life

To make this recipe, you'll need a really good kitchen

> From some hypothesizes you need a planet with the right conditions

Our neighbors, for example, couldn't even use it to make a chicken

> could refer our neighbor planets

Above all, your temperature setting has to be good
Otherwise it won't work, and you won't get any food

> again based on hypothesizes of chemically life creation you need right temperature

When you've set up the ingredients, add water and wait

> the water is essential

It may take a while, don't be alarmed if it gets late

> no one knows how much time is needed to synthesize life

When it's done it'll be worth it, I promise you that
You'll have so much to eat, I'm sure you'll get fat

> for sure - all life is used to feed something else.

The one time we tried it, it was quite a success
Though I dare say it made a bit of a mess

> our world was this "one time" and it is worthy, though a little bit messy

And about the title:

> Don't try this at home, because it was already done at our home planet ;)

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer:

> Some sort of plant that produces food? (Apple tree, wheat, corn, etc)

To make this recipe, you'll need a really good kitchen

> Kitchen could refer to a plot of land, as suggested by [@paste](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32229/dont-try-this-at-home/32231?noredirect=1#comment96511_32231).

Our neighbors, for example, couldn't even use it to make a chicken

> Well, kitchen tools don't help you plant plants and, as far as I know, plants don't make chicken.

Above all, your temperature setting has to be good
Otherwise it won't work, and you won't get any food

> Certain plants only thrive at certain temperatures.

When you've set up the ingredients, add water and wait

> Plants need water.

It may take a while, don't be alarmed if it gets late

> Watching a plant grow is worse than watching paint dry.

When it's done it'll be worth it, I promise you that
You'll have so much to eat, I'm sure you'll get fat

> When a plant finishes growing and has ripe food, you have so much food.

The one time we tried it, it was quite a success

> Congrats!

Though I dare say it made a bit of a mess

> It's messy, with all the soil and such.

Now tell me, my friends: what came out - can you guess?

> See top of the answer.

Comment: Nope, that's not it, but there is perhaps a kernel of truth (pun intended) hiding in this suggestion. In a manner of speaking at least...

Comment: Ah, it's the Linux kernel! It matches a lot of the things, actually.

Comment: Does it? I don't see the connection. But nice idea anyway.

Comment: You don't use a computer to make chicken, the temperature has to be fine or your computer burns up, it takes a while for you to debug and such, you sell your kernel and get rich so you get lots of food, and it's messy! :P

Comment: I guess. Good luck installing Linux by adding water to your computer :-)

Comment: This answer seems to fit all the clues quite well. You could just say that the "kitchen" is a nice garden or plot of land.

Comment: @paste I added that in.

Comment: @paste I agree, overall it's not bad. My intended answer fits the clues even better however. And as I said, this answer does contain an important idea that has at least a faint connection or echo of the intended answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Brewing beer

```
To make this recipe, you'll need a really good kitchen
```

> You'll need a rather complex equipment for this.  Well, at least it's more complicated than a pot for cooking eggs or a pan for frying a steak.

```
Our neighbors, for example, couldn't even use it to make a chicken
```

> No, chicken cannot be made using this equipment.

```
Above all, your temperature setting has to be good
```

> Right.  You have to keep a constant temperature for quite a time (at least several days).

```
Otherwise it won't work, and you won't get any food
```

> It will spoil if the temperature isn't properly set.

```
When you've set up the ingredients, add water and wait
```

> You need ingredients (always containing water) and quite some time.

```
It may take a while, don't be alarmed if it gets late
```

> Yeah.  Wait.

```
When it's done it'll be worth it, I promise you that
```

> Actually, I don't like beer that much, so you would be hard pressed to keep this promise.

```
You'll have so much to eat, I'm sure you'll get fat
```

> The remains of the brewing process is draff, which can be used to make bread.

```
The one time we tried it, it was quite a success
Though I dare say it made a bit of a mess
```

> I guess.  Cleaning up all the equipment afterwards is no fun.

Comment: Interesting idea, but no, that's not it. Note that I'm not seeing anything special about your answer that could distinguish it from other proposals. The correct answer will (hopefully) not be subject to such criticism.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is …

> Incubating eggs to get chicken

?

Comment: No, still not it I'm afraid.

Comment: *...chicken...*